# Cannot Require Popper with Webpack

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

I'm attempting to move my javascript files to Webpack. I'm not very familiar with Webpack so I am not sure that I have coded any of this correctly. I am trying to load jquery-ui, popper, and bootstrap 4. However, I am getting an error when requiring `Popper`. Please note that I am using the Wepacker gem for Ruby on Rails.

I have included the following code in my environment.js file to include jQuery automatically in each file.

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery'
}))

module.exports = environment
```

This part works. So, from there I ran `yarn add jquery-ui`.

Then in my /pack/application.js file I included `require('jquery-ui')`.

From my js file the following code prints to my console:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (jQuery.ui) {
      console.log("loaded");
    }
});
```

After this I tried installing and requiring `popper` with `yarn add popper`.

Then calling popper from inside my `document.ready` function I get an error:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    console.log(window.Popper)

});
```

The error:

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /home/ubuntu/environment/node_modules/path-platform/path.js: 'return' outside of function (32:2)

  30 | if (_path.posix) {
  31 |   module.exports = _path;
  32 |   return;
     |   ^
  33 | }
  34 | 
  35 | // resolves . and .. elements in a path array with directory names there
    at Parser.raise (home/ubuntu/environment/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:6420)
    at Parser.parseReturnStatement 
(home/ubuntu/environment/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10370)
    at Parser.parseStatementContent 
(home/ubuntu/environment/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10057)
    at Parser.parseStatement (home/ubuntu/environment/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10009)
    at Parser.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody 
(home/ubuntu/environment/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10585)
    at Parser.parseBlockBody (home/ubuntu/environment/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10572)
    at Parser.parseBlock (home/ubuntu/environment/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10556)
    at Parser.parseStatementContent 
    (home/ubuntu/environment/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10085)
    at Parser.parseStatement (home/ubuntu/environment/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10009)
    at Parser.parseIfStatement 
    (home/ubuntu/environment/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10363)
    at Parser.parseStatementContent 
    (home/ubuntu/environment/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10054)
    at Parser.parseStatement (home/ubuntu/environment/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10009)
    at Parser.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody 
    (home/ubuntu/environment/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10585)
at Parser.parseBlockBody (home/ubuntu/environment/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10572)
at Parser.parseTopLevel (home/ubuntu/environment/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9940)
at Parser.parse (home/ubuntu/environment/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11447)
at parse (home/ubuntu/environment/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11483)
at parser (home/ubuntu/environment/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/normalize-file.js:168)
at normalizeFile (home/ubuntu/environment/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/normalize-file.js:102)
at runSync (home/ubuntu/environment/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:44)
at runAsync (home/ubuntu/environment/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:35)
at process.nextTick (home/ubuntu/environment/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:34)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61)
at Object../node_modules/path-platform/path.js (index.js:82)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:1)
at Object../node_modules/parents/index.js (index.js:39)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:19)
at Object../node_modules/module-deps/index.js (index.js:623)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:3)
at Object../node_modules/browserify/index.js (index.js:846)
```

Here is my pack/application.js file

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()

require('jquery-ui')
require('popper')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just did the same thing, then realized what the issue was. [popper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/popper) is some kind of advanced browser testing library in Node. Bootstrap depends on [popper.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/popper.js) , which is a tooltip popup library for the browser.

So to fix this, you'll want to:

```
yarn remove popper
yarn add popper.js
```